# Python Syntax Error: Object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, syntax-error

Here is my current code:

```
x = int(3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679)

q = int(input("How many digits of Pi would you like to Print?"))

print(x[1:y])
```

Sorry if that Code indenting thing didn't work, I didn't understand it.

You see, I know that it can't convert the string variable as a literal term into the integer, but what would I do from here?

The code is supposed to print Pi to a chosen amount of characters.

Comment: Error message clear - you can't subscript `int` variable

Comment: Also, why did you make `pi` an int. No matter what you do here, it will always print `3.0000...`.

Comment: where do that `y` come from in place of `q`?! Either use `y` or `q`.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for this task. To have a variable number of decimals, you simply need to parameterize that value

```
from decimal import Decimal
x = decimal(3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679)

q = int(input("How many digits of Pi would you like to Print?"))

print("{0:.{width}f}".format(x, width=q))
```

---

Notice that the `width` variable in the print statement is your user input. Also notice I changed your definition of `pi` from an `int` to a `decimal` (because a `float` loses precision).

Examples:

```
How many digits of Pi would you like to Print?5
3.14159

How many digits of Pi would you like to Print?10
3.1415926536

How many digits of Pi would you like to Print?25
3.1415926535897931159979635
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
 x = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679"

y = int(input("How many digits of Pi would you like to Print?"))

print(x[1:y+1])
```

You can't use integers as list. But because the power of python you can render strings. Also care your variable names. Finally because python starts to count from 0 to n, nth number must be n+1 th position.